# MFC built using /clr compiler option - CString/System::String conversion

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, mfc, clr

I've got a fairly large MFC application that has just been migrated from VS6.0 to VS2008. It was a pretty painful process, but now I'd like to explore any managed-code options that may be available. I was able to successfully build the project using the /clr switch which seems to give me access to managed types.

I'd like to know if conversion between System::String and CString is automatic or not. The MSDN documentation that I've found suggests that this conversion isn't automatic but I haven't found this to be the case.  All three of the examples below work and both 1 and 2 are documented by the MSDN. What I'm curious about is example 3 which also works but I don't know why. The CurrentDirectory property is returning a pointer into the managed heap, String^, but why am I able to assign it to a CString? Exactly what is example 3 doing and what are the memory management implications?

Example 1)

```
    marshal_context ^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
    String ^env = System::Environment::CurrentDirectory;
    const char* env2 = context->marshal_as(env);
    AfxMessageBox(env2);
    delete context;
```

Example 2)

```
    CString s(System::Environment::CurrentDirectory);
    AfxMessageBox(s);
```

Example 3)

```
    CString s = System::Environment::CurrentDirectory;
    AfxMessageBox(s);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 3 works for pretty much the same reason option 2 does.  CString::operator= has an overload for System::String. Don't forget that the assignment operator can do a lot more than copy a reference.

This page:
[How to: Convert Between Various String Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx)
is *very* useful for mixed apps. [pin_ptr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh(VS.80).aspx) is great.

Be wary of sprinkling managed code around. I also work on a large MFC application that went /clr and I sometimes wish that we had done it in select libraries only. It can make debugging painful when there are a lot of managed-native transitions on the callstack. There are [performance considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky8kkddw.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can go from a system::String to CString because they share a common conversion (lptstr?) going to a System::String from CString will always need System::String^ test = gcnew System::String( CStringVar );